# how to compare year from date value type in database to today's year

Tags: sql

How to compare the year today from database year(date value type)

Here is the data in database > 2012-11-13 00:00:00.000

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT applicationId)
FROM custleaseapplication
WHERE @dateOfApplication(year) == year today
```

Comment: It looks more like SQL question, not C#. Are you using T-SQL?

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: What is `@dateOfApplication`? Why aren't you using `year` as is? If it's a function, what is its definition? By applying a function to a column you are preventing SQL Server from using any indexes on the column

Comment: @dateOfApplication is column in my database it is datetime value type. this is the example data from data base 2012-11-13 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GetDate` to get the current `DateTime` in sql-server and you can use `YEAR` to get the year of a datetime as int.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT applicationId) 
FROM custleaseapplication 
WHERE YEAR(DateColumn) = YEAR(GetDate())
```

Comment: it's not working the data type of date column is datetime. it din't work it still count every data.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE YEAR(@dateOfApplication) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

While

```
WHERE YEAR(DateColumn) = YEAR(GetDate())
```

will get the data you want, it will also force the database to do a full table scan instead of using any indexes on the column.

If `year` is the actual 4-digit year, you can simply write

```
WHERE Year >= YEAR(GetDate())  AND Year < YEAR(GetDate()) +1
```

This will work if `Year` is a numeric type.

If the column is a text type, it will *probably* work as SQL Server will convert the result of `YEAR()` to text before comparing. Differences in collation could prevent the server from using any underlying indexes though, forcing a table scan.